# How should I store subjects, lessons, URLs and output them in a list, in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**What I'm trying to achieve in React is a list like this**: http://output.jsbin.com/riceduhece

```
  <ul>
  <span>Mathematics:</span>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson3</a></li>
  <span>Programming:</span>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson3</a></li>
  <span>Music:</span>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lesson3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Mathematics, Programming and Music are subjects and they each have 3 lessons. Each lesson has a corresponding hyperlink.

**What have I tried?**
I have created an array with the subjects and was able to loop over them.

```
const subjects = ['Mathematics', 'Programming', 'Music'];

{subjects.map(subject => <p className="subject-label" key={subject}>{subject}</p>)}
```

**Where am I stuck at?**
I don't know how to store/query everything(subjects, lessons, URLs for each lesson). Do I need an array of objects? How should the structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the data in an object like so:

```
const data = {
  "Math": [
    { name: "lesson 1", url: "http://google.com" },
    { name: "lesson 2", url: "http://google.com" },
  ],
  "Programming": [
    { name: "lesson 1", url: "http://google.com" },
    { name: "lesson 2", url: "http://google.com" },
  ],
  "Music": [
    { name: "lesson 1", url: "http://google.com" },
    { name: "lesson 2", url: "http://google.com" },
  ]
}
```

and rendering by iterating over each array of objects using the object keys like so:

```
const Lesson = ({url, name}) => 
  <li>
    <a href={url}>{name}</a>
  </li>;

const Subject = ({ name, lessons }) =>
  <li>
    <h3>{name}</h3>
    <ul>
      {lessons.map(lesson =>
        <Lesson key={lesson.name} {...lesson} />
      )}
    </ul>
  </li>;

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    {Object.keys(data).map(key => 
      <Subject key={key} name={key} lessons={data[key]} />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/04k5kz6r3l

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well.
In my opinion you should store each one of the topics as an object.

```
const subjects = [
  {
  type: 'Mathematics',
  lessons: [
    {
      href: 'http://....',
      name: 'Lesson1'
    },...
  ], ... },
  {
  type: 'Programming',
  lessons: [
    {
      href: 'http://....',
      name: 'Lesson1'
    },
    {
      href: 'http://....',
      name: 'Lesson2'
    },...
  ]
}, ...];
```

and then just iterate over it and return the structure you want for your application:

```
<ul>
  {subjects.map(subject => {
    const lessons = subject.lessons.map( s => {
      return <li><a href={s.href}>{s.name}</a></li>
    }
    return (
     <div>
      <span>{subject.type}</span>
      {lessons}
     </div>
    );
  }}
</ul>
```

I put every subject inside a div so it will hold it together.

EDIT: just saw radix answer. I would go with his solution. much more readable and correct (using the type of the lesson as a key)